# Validate a cell containing formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have validated a cell by data validation.
Now, it can hold only values between 0 to 100. if user enters value out of range i.e. below 0 or above 100 a message box appears to inform that  **value must be between 0 to 100.**

I have also validated another cell with same range of values as above but it depends on other cells(i.e. it containing formula) but if the result is **out of range** i.e. below 0 or above 100 message box does not appear.

I want to display a **message box to inform user check your values.**
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do it outside of VBA. Here is some VBA to add to your sheet to get this functionality:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("TestCell") > 100 Then
    MsgBox "Check your inputs."
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the data validation rule in the cell which your formula depends on.
If, for example, you have `=2*A1` in B1 and you have set data validation for B1 (for example `between 0 and 100`), set validation for A1 instead (for example `between 0 and 50`).

Comment: What if there are two variables?

Comment: My formula depends upon four or five cells

Comment: Let say for example that your formula is in A1. Then set the conditional formatting custom rule (A1<=100)*(A1>=0) in ALL the cells your formula depends on. If you do not want or you cannot, write a VBA subroutine as suggested by Sux2Lose.